# how to detect whether scrolling up or scrolling down in radlistview

Tags: nativescript, gesture, radlistview

native script rad-list-view not detecting whether swiping up or swiping down the item list.

by using native script swipe event one will get 4 values for left, right, top, and bottom i.e 1,2,4,8. but swipe action is not working on rad-list-view.

```
        <lv:RadListView pullToRefresh="true" pullToRefreshInitiated="{{onPullToRefreshInitiated}}"
        scrolled="onScrolled" scrollOffset="scrollOffset" scrollStarted="onScrollStarted" scrollEnded="onScrollEnded"
        id="id_content" row="1" items="{{ source }}" loaded="onLoaded" backgroundColor="transparent"
        itemLoading="onItemLoading" itemTap="onItemTap">

            <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical" 
                backgroundColor="antiquewhite" margin="5" padding="10" borderWidth="1">

                    <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ name }}"/>
                    <Label fontSize="14" text="{{ name }}"/>

                </StackLayout>
            </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>

            <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                <lv:ListViewStaggeredLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2"/>
            </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>

            <lv:RadListView.pullToRefreshStyle>
                <lv:PullToRefreshStyle indicatorColor="red" indicatorBackgroundColor="antiquewhite"/>
            </lv:RadListView.pullToRefreshStyle>

        </lv:RadListView>

    </GridLayout>
```

how to detect swipe up or down event on radlistview.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the `scrollOffset` between `scrollStarted` and `scrollEnded` event, if start position is less than end position, then user has scrolled up, down otherwise.

```
let lastOffset;

export function onScrollStarted(args) {
    lastOffset = args.object.getScrollOffset();
}

export function onScrollEnded(args) {
    let currentOffset = args.object.getScrollOffset();
    console.log(currentOffset < lastOffset ? "Up" : "Down");
    lastOffset = currentOffset;
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=reZGFR)

Comment: this was working but not as expected. i'm animating action bar i.e hiding when scroll down and showing when scrolled up. but from the above answer, when i scroll down instantly the animation will not execute. only after scrolling end, action bar will get hidden. is there any suggestions for this problem....

Comment: Your question was about detecting scroll up / down, so I had to think of best options without hitting events too many times. If you want to instantly detect whether user is scrolling up / down, then just use the `scrolled` event instead of `scrollEnded` event.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i just changed scrollEnded event to onScrollDragEnded event. this works great. but, on animating i'm noticing some glitches and i also observed animation is not smooth compared to using listView. thank you.....